The pronoun in short yes/no answers to rhetorical tag-questions with the generic "you"
Here are a few (proverbial) truths put as rhetorical tag-questions:

You catch more flies with honey than with vinegar, don't you?


If you want to succeed, you need to work hard, don't you?


You cannot unscramble eggs, can you?


You create your own luck, don't you?

What's ailing me is the pronoun I should use in short yes/no answers to those.
That is, should I use "I"  as in "Yes, I do (No, I don't)/No I can't (Yes, I can)", or "you"—as in "Yes, you do (No, you don't)/No, you can't (Yes, you can)"?
Hard as I might, I couldn't find this question having been discussed anywhere on the net.
I may be wrong, but to me using "I" sounds somewhat awkward since the statements are phrased from a general perspective addressing someone else –not me, personally.
What do you, native speakers of the English language,  say to this?

We use 'you' when speaking generally. You can't get blood out of a stone, can you?

No, you can't—which means you're right: You can't get blood out of a stone. Correct?

@MichaelHarvey, does your comment mean that I can label my question "solved"? If this was the answer, which it definaely is, could it be put in the answer box? I'd like to upvote it. Maybe you'd feel like adding some details since there's been nothing on it online, so far. Otherewise, I wouldn't have posted my question here :-)

Even with non-rhetorical questions in which the "you" means the other person, the tag question still uses "you":  "You have finished your report, haven't you?"

In English, when rhetorical tag questions are phrased with "you" (as in "You catch more flies with honey than with vinegar, don't you?"), the "you" is typically understood as referring to people in general, rather than the person being spoken to directly.
Because of this general reference, it's more natural to respond using "you" in the short answer, as you're affirming the general truth implied in the question. Using "I" would sound awkward because it would make the statement about yourself specifically, which isn't the point of these types of general truths.

Once upon a time, English had a dedicated pronoun for this. "One" is still understood in this sense (e.g. "one catches more flies with honey than vinegar"), but it's usually seen as archaic or literary.

@wizzwizz4 "One does not simply walk into Mordor".
